# How to Get The Value From a Option That Got Selected, Using The select_tag helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to get the value of the option that got selected on the < select > that was build using the select_tag helper in Ruby on Rails.

The code goes like this:

```
<%= f.label "Favorite Team" %>
<%= select_tag :fav_league, options_for_LEAGUEs, :onchange => 'check1()' %>
```

I want this value because, depending on which option was selected, a different < select > will appear to the user. 
Example: There is a form and I want to know what is the name of the county that this user lives in, so I create a first < select > where the user select the State. Depending on what option he choosed, a different group of options will appear on the second < select > ( where he chooses his county, **and** this is what is going to be submit with the form, without the State initials.) The same occurs on my web app, but with National Leagues and Teams ( that's why options_for_LEAGUEs ( an array with the name of every League ) )

Ps: I want it in Ruby, if it can be moved to javascript it would be better, but you have to explain how

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You are asking us how to get the option... but where do you want to use the option? Are we talking about: a) during your specs to make sure the right option has been selected or b) in the app, after the user has clicked submit and you are deciding what to do with the selected option or c) in the app's interface in order to decide to display something different to the user? d) something I haven't thought of ? Also - please edit your question and show us the code that you've tried to figure this out (even if it's not working). You have put the effort in yes? :)

Comment: Edited! As I am very newbie on Rails i didn't have tried anything at all, only something like this `<%= val = select_tag :fav_league, options_for_LEAGUEs, :onchange => 'check1()' %>`

Answer (score 0):

> The code goes like this:
>
> ```
> <%= f.label "Favorite Team" %>
> <%= select_tag :fav_league, options_for_LEAGUEs, :onchange => 'check1()' %>
> ```
>
> How to get the value of the option that got selected on the `<select>`
>   ...if it can be moved to javascript it would be better,

In your `select_tag()`, you specified a function `check1()` for the onchange attribute.  A function that is specified for an onchange attribute is a javascript function, and when the user makes a change to the select, the web browser will look around for a javascript function called check1() to execute.  Therefore, you need to define a javascript function called check1() in a js file.  In rails, you put js files in the app/assets/javascripts directory.  Here is an example:

app/assets/javascripts/users.js:

```js
function check1(select) {
  var options = select.options;
  var selected_index = select.selectedIndex;
  var selected_val = options[selected_index].value;
  var selected_text = options[selected_index].text;

  //Now that you have the selected option, do something with it:
  alert("val: " + selected_val + ", text: " + selected_text);

  //Or, maybe send the data to the server and your rails app:
  var post_data = {
    "fav_league": {"val": selected.val(), "text": selected.text()}
  };

  $.post('/users/dostuff', post_data, function(response_data) {
    $("#result").html(response_data); 
  });

}
```

Note the use of `this` in the onclick below:

app/views/users/index.html:

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/index.html.erb</p>

<% options_for_LEAGUEs = [
    ["league1", 1],
    ["league2", 2],
    ["league3", 3]
  ]
%>

<div>
<%= 
select_tag(
  :fav_league,
  options_for_select(options_for_LEAGUEs),
  onclick: 'check1(this)'
)
%>
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def dostuff
    if request.xhr?  #If this is an incoming ajax request...
      val = params['fav_league']['val']
      text = params['fav_league']['text']
      render plain: "You sent me: #{val}, #{text}"
    end

    #Otherwise, by default rails renders app/views/users/dostuff.html.erb
  end
end
```

Or, you can forgo the inline onclick in the html, and use jquery to install the onclick handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#fav_league").on("change", function() {
    var selected = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected");

    //Now that you have the selected option, do something with it:
    alert(
      "val = " + selected.val() + ", text = " + selected.text()
    );

    //Or, maybe send the data to the server and your rails app:
    var post_data = {
      "fav_league": {"val": selected.val(), "text": selected.text()}
    };

    $.post('/users/dostuff', post_data, function(response_data) {
      $("#result").html(response_data); 
    });

  });
});
```

**Response to comment:**

It's probably easier to dynamically create a single team select based on the league choice, then let the user submit the form to send the team choice to the server.  Here's an example:

You can use an empty `<div>` with a data attribute in your view, and use rails to insert the team names into the data attribute, which will allow javascript executing in the browser to retrieve those names from the html:

```rb
<%= content_tag :div, id: "teams_div", data: {teams: @teams_for_league} do %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/index.html.erb</p>

<div>
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: 'dostuff', method: "post"} do |f| %>

<%= f.label "Favorite Team" %>
<%= select_tag(
  :fav_league, 
  "<option disabled selected>--select league--</option>#{options_for_select(@leagues)}".html_safe
)
%>

<%= content_tag :div, id: "teams_div", data: {teams: @teams_for_league} do %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit('Submit') %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Note that if you don't call `html_safe()` on the options string, the options may not get created correctly.  `options_for_select()` will take care of that for you, but if you want to add custom styles to an option and manually add it to the options string, then you need to call `html_safe()`.

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(1)

    @leagues = [
      ["league1"],
      ["league2"],
      ["league3"],
    ]

    @teams_for_league = {
      league1: ["team1", "team2"],
      league2: ["team3", "team4"],
      league3: ["team5", "team6", "team7"],
    }

  end

  def dostuff
    puts "-" * 10
    p params
    puts "-" * 10

    team_choice = params[:team_select]

    if team_choice 
      puts "**** The user chose: #{team_choice} *****" 
    else  #The user failed to select a team...
      redirect_to action: :index
    end

  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/users.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#fav_league").on("change", function() {
      var $selected = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected");
      var league_choice = $selected.text();
      var $teams_div = $('#teams_div');
      var teams_arr = $teams_div.data("teams")[league_choice];
      var team_name,
          $new_select;

      $teams_div.empty();

      $new_select = $(
          '<select>', 
          {name: "team_select"}
      ).appendTo($teams_div);

      $new_select.append(
          $("<option>", 
            {disabled: true, selected: true}
          ).text("--select team--")
      );

      for (team_name of teams_arr) {
        $new_select.append(
          $("<option>").text(team_name).attr('value', team_name)
        );
      };

    });
});
```

If you choose a team, then submit the form, you'll see the following output in the window where your server is running:

```
...
...
----------
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch",
"authenticity_token"=>"By2pZpUTxK2JZHBHYA7C4tryFTx2btBLnoGjdYpiOxPeHaHcLAO0VJue64HlTLGVLHzkZkdj4SRqAAt85Mn32A==",    
"fav_league"=>"2", "team_select"=>"team4", "commit"=>"Submit",  
"method"=>"post", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"dostuff"}                            
----------
**** The user chose: team4 *****
  Rendered users/dostuff.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 19.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: check1() is a function on the bottom of the page.It hides the < select >'s that won't be used by the user. ( I have one < select > for each League, and depending on which League he chooses, a different group of teams will appear, I don't know if its Bad Practice). So this function hides all of it, and then remove de _hide_ on the < select > that contains teams from that League. That's why the value is important to me. And the name of the team is what is important to POST, not the league

Comment: @RedManBrasil:  *I don't know if its Bad Practice* -- It's probably easier to just dynamically create one select for the team choices based on the league choice.   I added an example to the bottom of my answer.